# How to assign a resource group to a user in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not sure if I have understood MySQL resource groups correctly.

According to [the official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resource-groups.html):

> MySQL supports creation and management of resource groups, and permits assigning threads running within the server to particular groups so that threads execute according to the resources available to the group. Group attributes enable control over its resources, to enable or restrict resource consumption by threads in the group. DBAs can modify these attributes as appropriate for different workloads.

Eg.:

```
CREATE RESOURCE GROUP Batch
   TYPE = USER
   VCPU = 2-3            -- assumes a system with at least 4 CPUs
   THREAD_PRIORITY = 10;
```

So I presume we can assign different 'priorities' to different users using a database server instance.

How do we associate a resource group with a username specifically? I couldn't seem to find the information.

Comment: my first question would be why on earth you want such a thing, resource group a literally resources like cpus memory, privileges for users, so your question seems that you didn't read the link you provided completely

Answer (score 0):

You didn't scroll down far enough on the page you have linked. It says:

> If a session's own current thread should be in the Batch group, execute this statement within the session:
>
> ```
> SET RESOURCE GROUP Batch;
> ```
>
> Thereafter, statements in the session execute with Batch group resources.
>
> To execute a single statement using the Batch group, use the `RESOURCE_GROUP` optimizer hint:
>
> ```
> INSERT /*+ RESOURCE_GROUP(Batch) */ INTO t2 VALUES(2);
> ```

You could map resource groups to user names automatically by executing `SET RESOURCE GROUP` among the [`init_connect`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) commands.